# It is possible open s health application from another application and setting data input

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to know if it is possible to open my s health application (of my android smartphone), from another my application (android) that I'm building now.

But I want besides open the app, also set some data to this app, for example I want to set the aims, or any data. It is possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> It is possible to do this?

Yes!!

If you know the package name of the other app, here is an example which is *<sub>tested and working!!!!!</sub>*

(This demonstrates how to send a simple String value,modify params as you want )

```
openApp(yourActivity.this,"other.app.package.name","Hey I am coming catch me");
```

`

```
public static boolean openApp(Context context, String packageName,String dataNeedToPass) {
        PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
        try {
            Intent i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
            if (i == null) {
                return false;
                //pkg Name Not Found
            }
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            i.putExtra("KEY", dataNeedToPass);
            context.startActivity(i);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and in the launcher activity of the other side/app get the bundle

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if(bundle !=null){
    String myString = bundle.getString("KEY");
    }
```

**p.s** : If you want to send data make sure also the other app is modified and ready to catch!

Comment: @bircastri have you tested this?

Comment: I have see your answer but I don't know what are the values that "sHealth" application can accept. sHealth application is the application that you can download from android store (this application is build from samsung)

Comment: @bircastri  you cannot pass data to other applications in that way.I doubt even you know the package name of that application.Its **not possible** without knowing details

Comment: and next time when you post a question be specific may be you know the app called s Health but not everyone.So technically you are wasting someones time who wants to help you,because you have not given appropriate content!!